# How to get request headers in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, fiddler

```
https://www.sahibinden.com/en
```

If you open it incognito window and check headers in Fiddler then these are the two main headers you get:
[image]

When I click the last one and check request headers this is what I get
[image]

I want to get these headers in Python. Is there any way that I can get these using Selenium? Im a bit clueless here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170965/how-to-use-requests-library-with-selenium-in-python this may be useful for you!

Answer (score 28):

You can use Selenium Wire. It is a Selenium extension which has been developed for this exact purpose.

https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/

An example after pip install:

```
##  Import webdriver from Selenium Wire instead of Selenium
from seleniumwire import webdriver

##  Get the URL
driver = webdriver.Chrome("my/path/to/driver", options=options)
driver.get("https://my.test.url.com")

##  Print request headers
for request in driver.requests:
  print(request.url) # <--------------- Request url
  print(request.headers) # <----------- Request headers
  print(request.response.headers) # <-- Response headers
```

Comment: Any chance you might know if something similar exists for ruby? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I've only used selenium with Python :/

Comment: what the above package is doing is setting up a mitm proxy on selenium you can do this manually using mitmproxy also you might need to install the certificate of the selenium browser in order for it to function properly

Comment: Seems this package isn't actively maintained anymore. Lots of errors and hidden setup barriers to overcome

Answer (score 12):

You can run JS command like this;

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.open('GET', document.location, false)
req.send(null)
return req.getAllResponseHeaders()
```

On Python;

```
driver.get("https://t.me/codeksiyon")
headers = driver.execute_script("var req = new XMLHttpRequest();req.open('GET', document.location, false);req.send(null);return req.getAllResponseHeaders()")

# type(headers) == str

headers = headers.splitlines()
```

Comment: These are Response Headers. OP wants REQUEST headers

Answer (score 7):

The bottom line is, **No**, you can't retrieve the request headers using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491).

---

### Details

It had been a long time demand from the Selenium users to add the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) methods to read the HTTP status code and headers from a HTTP response. We have discussed about implementing this feature through Selenium at length within the discussion [WebDriver lacks HTTP response header and status code methods](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141).

However, Jason Leyba (Selenium contributor) in his [comment](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141#issuecomment-191404952) straightly mentioned:

> We will not be adding this feature to the WebDriver API as it falls outside of our current scope (emulating user actions).

Ashley Leyba further added, attempting to make WebDriver the ideal web testing tool will suffer in overall quality as `driver.get(url)` blocks until the browser has loaded the page and return the response for the final loaded page. So in case of a login redirects, status codes and headers will always end up with a 200 instead of the 302 you're looking for.

Finally, Simon M Stewart (WebDriver creator) in his [comment](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141#issuecomment-191405016) concluded that:

> This feature isn't going to happen. The recommended approach is to either extend the [HtmlUnitDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724856/htmlunitdriver-does-not-load-javascript-when-navigating-a-page-from-an-url/53744963#53744963) to access the information you require or to make use of an external proxy that exposes this information such as the [BrowserMob Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201944/how-to-use-browsermob-with-python-selenium/48266639#48266639)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use BrowserMob Proxy for this. Here is a example:

```
import settings

from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

config = settings.Config

server = Server(config.BROWSERMOB_PATH)
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy.proxy)
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,
    desired_capabilities=capabilities,
   executable_path=config.CHROME_PATH)

proxy.new_har("sahibinden", options={'captureHeaders': True})
driver.get("https://www.sahibinden.com/en")

entries = proxy.har['log']["entries"]
for entry in entries:
    if 'request' in entry.keys():
        print(entry['request']['url'])
        print(entry['request']['headers'])
        print('\n')

proxy.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and this doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```py
js_headers = '''
    const _xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    _xhr.open("HEAD", document.location, false);
    _xhr.send(null);

    const _headers = {};

    _xhr.getAllResponseHeaders().trim().split(/[\\r\\n]+/).map((value) => value.split(/: /)).forEach((keyValue) => {
        _headers[keyValue[0].trim()] = keyValue[1].trim();
    });

    return _headers;
'''

page_headers = driver.execute_script(js_headers)

type(page_headers) # -> dict
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you should see how do I write a good answer which must have some explanation about the code, [answer].

Comment: this captures response headers, while the original question asked to get reqeuest headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/ a plug-in replacement for webdriver adding request/response manipulation even for https by using its own local ssl certificate.

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome() # make sure chrome/chromedriver is in path
d.get('https://en.wikipedia.org')
vars(d.requests[-1].headers)
```

will list the headers in the last requests object list:

```
{'policy': Compat32(), '_headers': [('content-length', '1361'), 
('content-type', 'application/json'), ('sec-fetch-site', 'none'), 
('sec-fetch-mode', 'no-cors'), ('sec-fetch-dest', 'empty'), 
('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36'), 
('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br')],
'_unixfrom': None, '_payload': None, '_charset': None,
'preamble': None, 'epilogue': None, 'defects': [], '_default_type': 'text/plain'}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible to get headers using Selenium. [Further information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882645/how-to-grab-headers-in-python-selenium-webdriver)

However, you might use other libraries such as `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` to get headers.

Comment: These headers are shown only in icognito window when site is first visited. Then cookies are stored and this page is not visited. Would BS be able to capture those headers every time it is run?

Comment: Can you share any resources?

Comment: You can use requests to get HTML content and headers. It doesn't cache by default. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198274/how-do-i-clear-cache-with-python-requests)
Then, you can parse this HTML with BeautifulSoup if necessary.

Comment: I need request headers and not response headers

Comment: Can I intercept requests being made to url?